# Javascript Variable Scope - and function scope

Tags: javascript

I have below code, I declared valuables globally in the file, and then I assigned value to the variable with in function.
but when I tried to read the variable outside the function it gave undefined.

```
let latitude, longitude, IPLocation;
start(path)
console.log(IPLocation) // not work

async function start(path) {
IPLocation = await getData(path);
latitude = IPLocation.location.lat;
longitude = IPLocation.location.lng;
console.log(IPLocation) // work fine
}

async function getData(path) {
const data = await fetch(path);
const scrampled = await data.json();
parsed = await JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(scrampled));
return parsed
}
```

why that happen?

Comment: it has nothing to do with returning, he's changing the global variable inside the function but he does not await for that function to return before his `console.log` call

Comment: Why are you parsing the JSON and then immediately stringifying it and then parsing it again?

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because the function is `async` and you do not `await` for it.

```js
let latitude, longitude, IPLocation;
await start(path)
console.log(IPLocation) // should work now

async function start(path) {
  IPLocation = await getData(path);
  latitude = IPLocation.location.lat;
  longitude = IPLocation.location.lng;
  console.log(IPLocation) // work fine
}

async function getData(path) {
  const data = await fetch(path);
  const scrampled = await data.json();
  parsed = await JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(scrampled));

  return parsed
}
```

OR if you are not in a module script (so you can't have top level `await`, use `.then`).

```js
let latitude, longitude, IPLocation;
start(path).then(() => {
  console.log(IPLocation) // should work now
})
```

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that top-level `await` [is only available in JavaScript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#top_level_await).

Comment: it doesn't work, and gave error, "Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions, async generators and modules"

Comment: yes, as Andy mentioned you need to be in a `module` script.

Comment: you can use the `.then` method if you're not in a javascript `module` , updated the answer as well